# Build Truth Table given Circuit

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I am having trouble understanding how to build a truth table given a circuit or expression. I believe I have the expression ones down but I can not figure out the ones where the circuit is given to us. So I will upload the picture of the circuit here is what I believe is the truth table. However I dont understand how to tell which one has an output.

[image]

The first and gate has X1, NotX2, X3

Second and gate has X1not, X2, X3

So:

[image]

So re traced my steps So on the red one from AND to OR would be X1*X2'*X3
On the blue line from AND to OR X1'*X2'X3

So f=X1*X2'*X3 + X1'*X2'*X3

Is there a trick to these, or where is a good place to learn this? Way my professor teaches does not make a ton of sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I dont understand how to tell which one has an output." - which *what* has an output?

Comment: The top inverter is used in two places into the AND gates.

Comment: I mean where we are using the Truth table. So I guess which values are in the "F" column of the truth table

Comment: I find it helps if you actually write the states on the input to the and gates... e.g. X1 /X2 and X3 on the pins of the first gate. I have also seen folks color code each state line, but for more than a few that just gets more confusing

Comment: So Correct me if I'm wrong boolean expression would be F=AB but I'm not sure why just can follow the logic of the lines and see that but not see how to prove on that with truth table.

Comment: Believe I added the color circuit of the flow path but not 100% it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put values on the inputs and go through the gates with calculation of result on each step (after each gate). And you should put on the input all possible values (as shown in your truth table draft)

For example:

```
if x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 0; then 
    A = 0 and 1 and 0 = 0; 
    B = 1 and 0 and 0 = 0; 
    F = 0 or 0 = 0;
```

So, thereby `F = 0; when x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 0;`

Next:

```
if x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 1; then 
    A = 0 and 1 and 1 = 0; 
    B = 1 and 1 and 1 = 1; 
    F = 0 or 1 = 1;
```

`F = 1; when x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 1;`

And so on to the end.

Update:

Completed truth table of the scheme:

```
X1 | X2 | X3 |  F
---|----|----|-----
0  | 0  | 0  |   0
0  | 0  | 1  |   1
0  | 1  | 0  |   0
0  | 1  | 1  |   0
1  | 0  | 0  |   0
1  | 0  | 1  |   1
1  | 1  | 0  |   0
1  | 1  | 1  |   0
```

Comment: Now I am more confused. Did I even set my table up right then? I should have 8 columns right cause 2^3=8?

Comment: Not columns, but rows. If you want I can continue to fill the truth table

Comment: Please would be appreciated. I believe I have the left side filled out right correct? So the "F" would only have a 1 on the column with "1 | 1 | 0"?

Comment: I'm not sure only one case would be when `F = '1'` or not, but exactly not in the case when `1 | 1 | 0`, because `AND` will have `'1'` on the output only when all inputs are `'1'`. Wait few minutes, I fill the truth table

Comment: -1 for doing OP's homework for them.

Comment: When I calculated the truth table I found that made mistake in calculations before. Now it is right. I'm sorry for the mistake, may be it was reason of your was confusion.

Comment: @ThePhoton what means OP? But how can I explain to him? May be after that he will understand and it will be more clear for him, isn't it?

Comment: @thePhoton, op is an adult and as such will not change. So his homework shows his competition capability, which is why no homework will matter...

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, that may be true but we shouldn't reward people who ask the internet to do their homework for them, or answerers who give them what they want.

Comment: Yes, yes. Byt also not to punish those who will to help.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, The initial answer was helpful. The edited answer with the complete solution was not helpful because OP will never learn anything from it.

Comment: Anyway will not learn. And we should not judge. Fk, i suddenly sound like a christian. Ok, waste him!

Comment: I do not know why you guys are getting so mad at him, cause I'm still trying to understand how to do it. I followed it thru and edited my answer working it with him. So not like I just asked him to do it. And that does make sense cause that makes the X1*X2'X3 and X1'*X2'X3. Thanks even tho everyone else is getting mad.

Comment: @noreturn you should learn it by yourself! It's basics!!